# Apache + mod_auth_tkt + mod_rewrite + mod_proxy from root directory

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have a web application running on a tomcat server which is "behind" an Apache httpd server and I am using mod_proxy to forward requests from the httpd to the tomcat server.
The httpd server is using mod_auth_tkt for authentication, which stores the info about the user in the environment variable REMOTE_USER. I pass this variable from the httpd to the tomcat server using mod_rewrite, saving it as a header (X-Forwarded-User).

The ProxyPass is set up as

```
httpd_server/app/ -> tomcat_server/app/
```

this is the vhost.conf:

```
<Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-User
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1,NS]
    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e
</Location>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass               /app/       http://127.0.0.1:8084/app/
        ProxyPassReverse        /app/       http://127.0.0.1:8084/app/
</IfModule>
```

And this works perfectly. But if try to change the ProxyPass to

```
httpd_server/ -> tomcat_server/app/
```

So changing the the vhost.conf to:

```
ProxyPass               /       http://127.0.0.1:8084/app/
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://127.0.0.1:8084/app/
```

Then the header (X-Forwarded-User) ends up empty (null) on the web application.

After further investigation I found out that if I try to forward a different variable, for example REMOTE_PORT (or even a string), everything works correctly for both configurations (The app recieves the header correctly).

Is there any obvious mistake why the forwarding of REMOTE_USER does not work when proxy-ing from the root directory? Did I miss something or could this be a mod_auth_tkt issue?